# How to use Linq to check tags within JSon

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, linq

I have below JSon File :-

```
{
  "requirements": {
    "-FileName": "sample.xls",
    "requirement": [
      {
        "desc": "Employee status        will be classified as: 
•   Assigned $ when employee is working on a project. 
•   Reserved when employee is scheduled to work on a project in near future. Unassigned when employee is not working on project.",
        "Id": "Req40"
      },
      {
        "Id": "NFR-2",
        "desc": "Team Leader should create resource allocation $% request in Maintain Project Module. Resource allocation request $@is associated with only one role. Project $@ Manager should provide roll-on date and roll-off date in resource allocation request."
      },
      {
        "Id": "req2",
        "desc": "PRMS must always be available except during the & @ scheduled maintenance. Scheduled maintenance must always be at 8PM on week days.",
        "message": "message of Req3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to check if Tags other than "Id" and "desc" are present in JSon.

For this I have used for loop as below :-

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRequirements; i++)
{
    int NumberOfTagsInJson = (obj["requirements"]["requirement"][i]).Count();
    if (NumberOfTagsInJson == 2) // checks if tag other than id and desc is present Eg. Message
    {
        var id = obj["requirements"]["requirement"][i]["Id"];
        if (id == null)
        {
            IsHavingValidTags = false;
            break;
        }

        var Desc = obj["requirements"]["requirement"][i]["desc"];
        if (Desc == null)
        {
            IsHavingValidTags = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        IsHavingValidTags = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I optimize it without using for loop.
Eg. I tried converting it into List as:-

```
(obj["requirements"]["requirement"]).ToList()
```

After this I wanted to use Linq to check if tags other than "Id" and "Desc" are present.

How can I use it?

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
IsHavingValidTags = obj["requirements"]["requirement"]
    .All(_ => _.Count() == 2 && _["Id"] != null && _["desc"] != null);
```

Comment: It is giving error : -Expression can not contain Lmbda expression.. See Edit1

Comment: Done.. Understood it can not be seen from watch window.. thanks this works

Comment: Hi, can you please help me on this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798228/check-all-properties-in-list