# Check all properties in List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have List of class as :-

```
 public class Requirement
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
    }
```

List lstRequirement

I have 3 records in this list for Id and desc.
I wanted to check if any of item is not remaining null.

For that I used below :-

```
bool IsHavingValidTags = lstRequirement.All(_=> _.Id!=null && _.desc!=null);
```

This condition is working fine with above Linq.
But I wanted to make it as Generic.

Eg. In future there may get added 5 more properties in Requirement class.
After addition of properties I also have to make changes in Linq.

How can I make this Linq condition generic for all properties?
I want to check any of the property is not remaining null in List.

Please help..!!!

I tried With =>

```
 bool IsHavingValidTags = lstRequirement.All(_ => _ != null);
```

But not giving desired result.

**EDIT 1 :**

[image]

Comment: i posted this answer still i am going to find the exact thing you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension method that uses reflection like the following:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool AreAllPropertiesNotNullForAllItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        return items.All(x => properties.All(p => p.GetValue(x) != null));
    }
}
```

then use like this:

```
bool IsHavingValidTags = lstRequirement.AreAllPropertiesNotNullForAllItems();
```

EDIT:

`PropertyInfo.GetValue(object obj)` method overload was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5. If you are using .NET Framework 4.0 you need to call `p.GetValue(x, null)`

Comment: No overload GetValues take 1 argument.. see Edit1

Comment: Done.. kept null in that place >>  return items.All(x => properties.All(p => p.GetValue(x,null) != null)); working fine for me

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework 4.0 or below? That is why p.GetValue(x) doesn't work. PropertyInfo.GetValue(object obj) overload was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this you should make those field `not null`. this will never allow those field inserted null. keep validations. like bellow.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
public string first_name { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
public string last_name { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is in WebApi.. not in web application

Comment: oh than i have to change my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop to loop through all the object in the list. Then use reflection to get all the properties in each item in the list,  then you can loop through those properties  to perform your null check.

```
    Foreach  (var x in lstRequirement){
List prop = x.GetType().GetProperties();
Foreach  (var y in prop){
If (y == null){
IsHavingValidTag = true;
//Then you can return you method here or throw an Exception 
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an static method to check the Properties of the Class.  I will show you the following example.

Instead of your code :

```
bool IsHavingValidTags = lstRequirement.All(_ => _ != null);
```

use the following codes:

```
  bool flg = list.All(m => CheckProperties(m));
  public static bool CheckProperties<T>(T source)
        {
            bool rtnFlg = true;
            Type t = typeof(T);
            var properties = t.GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                var value = prop.GetValue(source, null);
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return rtnFlg;
        }
```